# Bootstrap responsive works well on resizing browser but not works in phone

Tags: html, css

I have been using twitter bootstrap for responsive purpose.Responsive works well when i check by resizing browser but when i check on phone responsive does not works !!!

Seeking a good response regarding this issue  - Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Show us if there is an error or a print of mobile screen

Answer (score 6):

You should add this in your header to work correctly in phone.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed this,Add this to your HTML head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Ya I missed it initially but after inserting this line of code still the issue prevails !!!